# How to deserialize base64-encoded data and use it with DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, base64

My goal is to come up with an endpoint that gets a base64-decoded string. 
This is based described by an example

My input JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "encoded_data": "a2F0aWUsIGpvaG5zLCBrYXRpZUBnbWFpbC5jb20KdG9tbXksbGVlLHRvbW15QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ=="
}
```

I have tried to implement it the following way, but I end up with the following error message:

```
JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Looks like I've messed up the concepts. Really need help on this:

```
class UsersFileUpload(APIView):
    #parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        stream = base64.b64decode(request.data['encoded_data'])

        stream = io.BytesIO(stream)
        data = JSONParser().parse(stream) 
        serializer = UsersSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're decoding your text correctly, you shouldn't need to use `BytesIO`.

You should `decode` the byte string returned from `b64decode` and then pass it to the JSONParser.

```
b64decoded_data = base64.b64decode(request.data['encoded_data']).decode('UTF-8')
data = JSONParser().parse(b64decoded_data)
```